# Как пофиксить ошибку?

Tags: c#, youtube

отправляю запрос к ютубу, чтобы получить json ответ, но вылазит ошибка, как можно пофиксить?
(добавил)Я заметил такую штуку, что в параметре authorization SAPISIDHASH всё время меняется, может быть из-за этого? И если из-за этого, подскажите, пожалуйста, как его получать, чтобы был корректный вход?
(добавил)Короче, выпустил токен, вроде как, не ругается на него, но теперь такая ошибка
[image: Ошибка2]

```
var body = "{\"\"context\"\":{\"\"client\"\":{\"\"hl\"\":\"\"ru\"\",\"\"gl\"\":\"\"RU\"\",\"\"remoteHost\"\":\"\"83.221.223.190\"\",\"\"deviceMake\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"deviceModel\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"visitorData\"\":\"\"CgszNnBrYkRyMTUtcyjHs5GVBg%3D%3D\"\",\"\"userAgent\"\":\"\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)\"\",\"\"clientName\"\":\"\"WEB\"\",\"\"clientVersion\"\":\"\"2.20220609.00.00\"\",\"\"osName\"\":\"\"Windows\"\",\"\"osVersion\"\":\"\"10.0\"\",\"\"originalUrl\"\":\"\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oyf0feE9Ewo\"\",\"\"screenPixelDensity\"\":1,\"\"platform\"\":\"\"DESKTOP\"\",\"\"clientFormFactor\"\":\"\"UNKNOWN_FORM_FACTOR\"\",\"\"configInfo\"\":{\"\"appInstallData\"\":\"\"CMezkZUGELfLrQUQ2FELiLrgUQrp6uBRCYh64FEJjqrQUQmN79EhDUg64FEIKOrgUQkfj8EhDYvq0F\"\"},\"\"screenDensityFloat\"\":1.25,\"\"timeZone\"\":\"\"Europe/Moscow\"\",\"\"browserName\"\":\"\"Chrome\"\",\"\"browserVersion\"\":\"\"102.0.0.0\"\",\"\"screenWidthPoints\"\":886,\"\"screenHeightPoints\"\":754,\"\"utcOffsetMinutes\"\":180,\"\"userInterfaceTheme\"\":\"\"USER_INTERFACE_THEME_LIGHT\"\",\"\"connectionType\"\":\"\"CONN_CELLULAR_4G\"\",\"\"memoryTotalKbytes\"\":\"\"8000000\"\",\"\"mainAppWebInfo\"\":{\"\"graftUrl\"\":\"\"https://www.youtube.com/c/MusicLabWork/about\"\",\"\"pwaInstallabilityStatus\"\":\"\"PWA_INSTALLABILITY_STATUS_CAN_BE_INSTALLED\"\",\"\"webDisplayMode\"\":\"\"WEB_DISPLAY_MODE_BROWSER\"\",\"\"isWebNativeShareAvailable\"\":true}},\"\"user\"\":{\"\"lockedSafetyMode\"\":false},\"\"request\"\":{\"\"useSsl\"\":true,\"\"internalExperimentFlags\"\":[],\"\"consistencyTokenJars\"\":[]},\"\"clickTracking\"\":{\"\"clickTrackingParams\"\":\"\"CC8QuyJ0t2EpfgCFcU7mwod5WkExA==\"\"},\"\"adSignalsInfo\"\":{\"\"params\"\":[{\"\"key\"\":\"\"dt\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1654938056328\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"flash\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"0\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"frm\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"0\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_tz\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"180\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_his\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"5\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_h\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"864\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_w\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1536\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_ah\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"824\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_aw\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1536\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_cd\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"24\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"bc\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"31\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"bih\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"754\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"biw\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"870\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"brdim\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"0,0,0,0,1536,0,1536,824,886,754\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"vis\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"wgl\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"true\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"ca_type\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"image\"\"}],\"\"bid\"\":\"\"ANyPxKqh1o0fCfaE9JXKsulGKl1YwJt87cIFGt-6vXWVADoMYW2xftBUSfaJA06IcajngNTg\"\"}},\"\"recaptchaResponseToken\"\":\"\"" + token + "\"\",\"\"channelId\"\":\"\"" + channelId + "\"\"}";
```

[image: Ошибка]

````
string channelId = "тут id канала с искомой инфой";
var client = new RestClient("https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/channel/reveal_business_email?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&prettyPrint=false");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var reka = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            reka.AddHeader("authorization", "SAPISIDHASH 1654983168_86efccccc4ce76a207c8dbc53225bf74d9a7fa25");
            reka.AddHeader("cookie", "GPS=1; YSC=Pmcj0jfTjys; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=cbBdmXEM; PREF=f4=4000&tz=Europe.Moscow; SID=LAixPSjizRb1wGE5XpthD9cSaRf_b0MV6x6PQ9iEvnz9DsaM_yxHlVI7-4YtFQ.; __Secure-1PSID=LAixPSjizRb1wGE5XpthD9cSaRf_b0MV6x6PQOfyHF92It8NnIw0Kw3EVw.; __Secure-3PSID=LAixPSjizRb1wGE5XpthD9cSaRf_b0MV6x6PQ9iEv0EmNvUFjNQnM8OLIerg.; HSID=AYLuDIgi6Pf4ioxW4; SSID=ABFOGRe5RivJTtOJ_; APISID=nFtlS-kscWfNq-db/A-VpA3peIM0Qb6gkM; SAPISID=rE4tOmRPehuvYmn6QknSK52x; __Secure-1PAPISID=rE4tOmRPehuvY-Ie/AVEE4Pmn6QknSK52x; __Secure-3PAPISID=rE4tOmRPehuvY-Ie/AVEknSK52x; LOGIN_INFO=AFmbXPf-RMCljDBe4_GBAiEA-egMMIqJadSNoMQtyLrvTlxvlvcSgzVj98h9Z9BhB_c:QUQ3MjNmeGg2akd5cEQ5Y3VLOWJiR1ctY1c1ekdKdnFfOFc4NXgzOFFoRG5Pb3JjQjBSSkRMS2M2aFN1NU03N29USTRJYmlTVFJ4Nl8zZ244dVFIMGktaEVkOWMzUDEwWXVVaDRZQmVtR2dxhIdkczR0xoV1ZET011c2RHODY5M2R2TUtCaVNCWUQxOHFn; CONSISTENCY=ALOGzFzIXR_zL1oIczyNONY5v3Z5_oE4v9yYOuaBNLuTLzEPd5HnL359ShhC0pUPphhFfZ-h18yc4zXYWcXbMvgeUdNKGW; SIDCC=AJi4QaDy2c5nEE9XQs9mVR9iOfOIxw; __Secure-3PSIDCC=AJi4QfGGurkmeS1AVZyK5qa1satJ_xlHDXbpKjmjbxncqiuV2ms1How; SIDCC=AJi4QfEw8PSsHtVgn0RhslLGM5B01sHkwFi4GdO_3mRZ7Tj9DYdCSp-Tqcsg2HjRkaBvAwnVPQ; __Secure-3PSIDCC=AJi4QfGr-Ls7I1ovi8BkPdMTajVC-Gq010Yt8d4Aw");
            reka.AddHeader("accept-language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
            reka.AddHeader("origin", "https://www.youtube.com");
            reka.AddHeader("referer", link);
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua", "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"102\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"102\"");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-arch", "\"x86\"");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-bitness", "\"64\"");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-full-version", "\"102.0.5005.63\"");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-full-version-list", "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99.0.0.0\", \"Chromium\";v=\"102.0.5005.63\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"102.0.5005.63\"");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-model", "");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-platform-version", "\"10.0.0\"");
            reka.AddHeader("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
            reka.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var body = "{\"\"context\"\":{\"\"client\"\":{\"\"hl\"\":\"\"ru\"\",\"\"gl\"\":\"\"RU\"\",\"\"remoteHost\"\":\"\"83.221.223.190\"\",\"\"deviceMake\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"deviceModel\"\":\"\"\"\",\"\"visitorData\"\":\"\"CgszNnBrYkRyMTUtcyjHs5GVBg%3D%3D\"\",\"\"userAgent\"\":\"\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)\"\",\"\"clientName\"\":\"\"WEB\"\",\"\"clientVersion\"\":\"\"2.20220609.00.00\"\",\"\"osName\"\":\"\"Windows\"\",\"\"osVersion\"\":\"\"10.0\"\",\"\"originalUrl\"\":\"\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oyf0feE9Ewo\"\",\"\"screenPixelDensity\"\":1,\"\"platform\"\":\"\"DESKTOP\"\",\"\"clientFormFactor\"\":\"\"UNKNOWN_FORM_FACTOR\"\",\"\"configInfo\"\":{\"\"appInstallData\"\":\"\"CMezkZUGELfLrQUQ2JquBRCUj64Yh64FEJjqrQUQmN79EhDUg64FEIKOrgUQkfj8EhDYvq0F\"\"},\"\"screenDensityFloat\"\":1.25,\"\"timeZone\"\":\"\"Europe/Moscow\"\",\"\"browserName\"\":\"\"Chrome\"\",\"\"browserVersion\"\":\"\"102.0.0.0\"\",\"\"screenWidthPoints\"\":886,\"\"screenHeightPoints\"\":754,\"\"utcOffsetMinutes\"\":180,\"\"userInterfaceTheme\"\":\"\"USER_INTERFACE_THEME_LIGHT\"\",\"\"connectionType\"\":\"\"CONN_CELLULAR_4G\"\",\"\"memoryTotalKbytes\"\":\"\"8000000\"\",\"\"mainAppWebInfo\"\":{\"\"graftUrl\"\":\"\"https://www.youtube.com/c/MusicLabWork/about\"\",\"\"pwaInstallabilityStatus\"\":\"\"PWA_INSTALLABILITY_STATUS_CAN_BE_INSTALLED\"\",\"\"webDisplayMode\"\":\"\"WEB_DISPLAY_MODE_BROWSER\"\",\"\"isWebNativeShareAvailable\"\":true}},\"\"user\"\":{\"\"lockedSafetyMode\"\":false},\"\"request\"\":{\"\"useSsl\"\":true,\"\"internalExperimentFlags\"\":[],\"\"consistencyTokenJars\"\":[]},\"\"clickTracking\"\":{\"\"clickTrackingParams\"\":\"\"CC8Quy8YACITCOKJ0t2EpfgCFcU7mwod5WkExA==\"\"},\"\"adSignalsInfo\"\":{\"\"params\"\":[{\"\"key\"\":\"\"dt\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1654938056328\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"flash\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"0\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"frm\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"0\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_tz\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"180\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_his\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"5\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_h\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"864\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_w\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1536\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_ah\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"824\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_aw\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1536\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"u_cd\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"24\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"bc\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"31\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"bih\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"754\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"biw\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"870\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"brdim\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"0,0,0,0,1536,0,1536,824,886,754\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"vis\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"1\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"wgl\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"true\"\"},{\"\"key\"\":\"\"ca_type\"\",\"\"value\"\":\"\"image\"\"}],\"\"bid\"\":\"\"ANyPxKqh1o0fCfaE9JXKsulGKl1YwJt87cIFGt-6vXWVADoMYW2xft7fFp9jZKkCf9KBUSfaJA066DM8ETVPfU8BJIcajngNTg\"\"}},\"\"recaptchaResponseToken\"\":\"\"" + token + "\"\",\"\"channelId\"\":\"\"" + channelId + "\"\"}";
            reka.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse resp = client.Execute(reka);
            MessageBox.Show(resp.Content);

            email = resp.Content;```
````

Comment: В ошибке есть ссылка на документацию.

Comment: Прочитал документацию, но у меня вопрос, почему у меня требуется какая-то аутентификация для запроса, если при просмотре этого запроса в Postman, про это ничего не написано, а приложение я делаю не только для себя, и что тогда делать людям, которые получат это приложение, или как поступать мне, чтобы оно свободно было доступно для всех. Также имеется вопрос, на каком моменте проходить эту регистрацию?

Comment: Выделаете через реверс-инжиниринг, а надо через API по документации. Симуляция браузера плоха тем, что гугл в любой момент может поменять сайт и всё перестанет работать. С API они так делать не будут, у них много клиентов.

Comment: @aepot А сможете подсказать, как можно сделать это через API, и вы случайно не знаете,ка получать этот authorization токен? Пробовал выпустить через гугл аккаунт, но теперь чуть другая ошибка, в которой пишется, что я не авторизовался и выдаёт ошибку 401

Comment: Не подскажу, не разбирался, но у гугла по API должна быть вполне вменяемая документация. Либо если они хотят OAuth2, то читайте документацию по этому стандарту.

Comment: @aepot они, скорее всего, хотят SAPISIDHASH , а как генерировать его, я не знаю